# Having problems getting Weight Data with Android from a BLE Scale

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently developing an android app for a weight scale I received that transmits data through bluetooth low energy.

I was looking at documentation and if I got the information correctly, there are specific UUIDs for data. I received a BLE scale with a Chinese protocol document found here: http://www.anj.fyi/protocol.pdf

I found and was able to get a functioning scanner working that lists the device name and the UUIDs it broadcasts.

Lets say I want just the weight data to show up in the UI, nothing else and nothing more.

I don't know what UUID they used for the weight data, and there are a lot of UUIDs. Probably 20+. I checked a UUID compilation and the usual weight data UUID does not show up.

How do I get the data from those UUIDs?

[image: http://imgur.com/a/mEoXH]

I'm thinking it might be the ones that are notifications, indications or read properties.

Looking at the UUID for example, f000ffc2.

How would I get data from that characteristic? Would anyone have an example code to grab the data from those UUIDs, or tutorials because I'm terribly lost right now.

I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There are no weight information on the document you list http://www.anj.fyi/protocol.pdf, it is only shows the BLE module hardware interface spec, i.e. it does not specify the detailed service and characteristic.(I an a native Chinese speaker).

Regarding to the UUID you want to know which is the one to represent the weight, yes you are right it should be the read/notification feature without write permission. Can you use the apps e.g. lightblue on iOS to receive the notification(meanwhile change the value on your device) to test it? this will help you to understand which characteristic is the one you want.

Comment: To suggest using an iOS app when the question is tagged [tag:android] is odd at best.